# How to run multiple expressions when an if condition is true?

Tags: if-statement, scheme

I'm new to Scheme and am trying to have an if-statement perform more than one action if its condition is true. I tried something like:

```
(if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
        ((+ count 1) (+ reference 1))
        ~else action, etc.~
```

And it complains about my action, saying

> application: not a procedure

If I remove the parentheses, so that the action for a true condition is:

```
(+ count 1) (+ reference 1)
```

It complains

> if: bad syntax

and fails to run at all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two problems with the code. The first, an `if` form can't have more than one expression in the consequent and in the alternative. Two possible solutions for that - you can either use `begin` (not just a couple of parenthesis, that's for procedure application) to surround multiple expression:

```
(if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
    ; needs an explicit `begin` for more than one expression
    (begin
      (+ count 1)
      (+ reference 1))
    ; needs an explicit `begin` for more than one expression
    (begin
      ~else action, etc~))
```

... or use a `cond`, which is a better alternative because it already includes an implicit `begin`:

```
(cond ((char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
       ; already includes an implicit `begin`
       (+ count 1)
       (+ reference 1))
      (else
       ; already includes an implicit `begin`
        ~else action, etc~))
```

The second problem is more subtle and serious, both of the expressions in the consequent part are probably not doing what you expect. This one: `(+ count 1)` is doing nothing at all, the incremented value is lost because you didn't use it after incrementing it. Same thing with the other one: `(+ reference 1)`, but at least here the value is being returned as the result of the conditional expression. You should either pass both incremented values along to a procedure (probably as part of a recursion):

```
(cond ((char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
       ; let's say the procedure is called `loop`
       (loop (+ count 1) (+ reference 1)))
      (else
        ~else action, etc~))
```

Or directly update in the variables the result of the increments, although this is not the idiomatic way to write a solution in Scheme (it looks like a solution in C, Java, etc.):

```
(cond ((char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
       ; here we are mutating in-place the value of the variables
       (set! count (+ count 1))
       (set! reference (+ reference 1)))
      (else
        ~else action, etc~))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to perform multiple actions with side-effects in one arm of the `if`, then you'll need to put them into a `begin`, like this:

```
(if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
    (begin (set! count (+ count 1))
           (set! reference (+ reference 1)))
    ~else action, etc.~
```

If, instead of causing changes in variables, you want to return two values at once, then you'll either need to combine the expressions into a single object, like this:

```
(if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
    (cons (+ count 1) (+ reference 1)))
    ~else expression~
```

in which case to pull out the count and reference, you'll need to apply `car` and `cdr` to the result of the `if`—or you could actually return multiple values, like this:

```
(if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
    (values (+ count 1) (+ reference 1)))
    ~else expression~
```

in which case to pull out the count and reference, you'll need to bind the multiple values to variables somehow in the code that calls the `if`. One way to do that is with `let-values`, possibly something like this:

```
(define count&ref
  (λ (str ch)
    (let loop ([loc 0] [count 0] [reference 0])
      ; whatever other stuff you're doing
      (if (char=? (string-ref str loc) ch)
          (values (+ count 1) (+ reference 1)))
          ~else expression~ )))

(let-values ([(new-count new-ref) (count&ref "some stuff" #\u)])
  ;in here, new-count and new-ref are bound to whatever count&ref returned
  )
```

On the other hand, if `count` and `reference` are variables that you're just keeping track of within a loop, the simplest way might be to call the next iteration of the loop inside the `if`, like this:

```
(let loop ([loc 0] [count 0] [reference 0])
  ; whatever other stuff you're doing
  (if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
      (loop (+ loc 1) (+ count 1) (+ reference 1))
      ~else expression~ ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `begin` to group a set of expressions to be executed one by one.

```
(if (char=? (string-ref str loc) #\a)
        (begin (+ count 1) (+ reference 1))
        ~else action, etc.~
```

`begin` only returns the value of the last expression, that is `(+ reference 1)`, so the value of `(+ count 1)` is not used.